# Retrieve drizzleContext from within componentDidMount

Tags: drizzle

How do i get drizzleContext from inside the componentDidMount function?
I am currently getting it from render using the following code which seems to be working fine:

```
  render() {
    return (
    <DrizzleContext.Consumer>


      {drizzleContext => {
        const { drizzle, drizzleState, initialized } = drizzleContext
        if (!initialized) {
          return "Loading..."
          }
.........
```